# Upgrade ram in Vaio Laptop fails

Tags: memory, sony-vaio

I have this [Sony VAIO VPC-EB3M1E](https://www.computeruniverse.net/en/products/90396215/sony-vaio-vpc-eb3m1e-wi-white-w7hp64.asp) which has 4 GB RAM (2GB in each slot)

From CPUID I get:

```
Chipset
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Northbridge Intel Havendale/Clarkdale Host Bridge rev. 02
Southbridge Intel HM55 rev. 05
Graphic Interface PCI-Express
PCI-E Link Width x16
PCI-E Max Link Width x16
Memory Type DDR3
Memory Size 4 GBytes
Channels Dual, (Symmetric)
Memory Frequency 532.1 MHz (4:16)
CAS# latency (CL) 7.0
RAS# to CAS# delay (tRCD) 7
RAS# Precharge (tRP) 7
Cycle Time (tRAS) 20
Row Refresh Cycle Time (tRFC) 60
Command Rate (CR) 1T
Host Bridge 0x0044
Host Bridge 0x2C62
Host Bridge 0x2D01
Host Bridge 0x2D10
Host Bridge 0x2D11
Host Bridge 0x2D12
Host Bridge 0x2D13

Memory SPD
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

DIMM # 1
SMBus address 0x50
Memory type DDR3
Module format SO-DIMM
Manufacturer (ID) Elpida (7F7FFE00000000000000)
Size 2048 MBytes
Max bandwidth PC3-10700 (667 MHz)
Part number EBJ21UE8BDS0-DJ-F 
Serial number D3101E6E
Manufacturing date Week 15/Year 10
Number of banks 8
Nominal Voltage 1.50 Volts
EPP no
XMP no
AMP no
JEDEC timings table CL-tRCD-tRP-tRAS-tRC @ frequency
JEDEC #1 5.0-5-5-14-19 @ 380 MHz
JEDEC #2 6.0-6-6-17-23 @ 457 MHz
JEDEC #3 7.0-7-7-20-27 @ 533 MHz
JEDEC #4 8.0-8-8-22-30 @ 609 MHz
JEDEC #5 9.0-9-9-24-33 @ 666 MHz

DIMM # 2
SMBus address 0x52
Memory type DDR3
Module format SO-DIMM
Manufacturer (ID) Elpida (7F7FFE00000000000000)
Size 2048 MBytes
Max bandwidth PC3-10700 (667 MHz)
Part number EBJ21UE8BDS0-DJ-F 
Serial number CC101E6D
Manufacturing date Week 15/Year 10
Number of banks 8
Nominal Voltage 1.50 Volts
EPP no
XMP no
AMP no
JEDEC timings table CL-tRCD-tRP-tRAS-tRC @ frequency
JEDEC #1 5.0-5-5-14-19 @ 380 MHz
JEDEC #2 6.0-6-6-17-23 @ 457 MHz
JEDEC #3 7.0-7-7-20-27 @ 533 MHz
JEDEC #4 8.0-8-8-22-30 @ 609 MHz
JEDEC #5 9.0-9-9-24-33 @ 666 MHz
```

The ram that it has now is [Elpida 2GB PC3-10600 DDR3-1333MHz non-ECC Unbuffered CL9](http://www.memory4less.com/m4l_itemdetail.aspx?itemid=1443586692&partno=EBJ21UE8BDS0-DJ-F)

and I purchased this ram [Kingston 8GB Kit (2 X 4GB) PC3-10600 DDR3-1333MHz non-ECC Unbuffered CL9](http://www.memory4less.com/m4l_itemdetail.aspx?itemid=1469246727&partno=KVR13S9S8K2/8)

The problem is that the laptop doens't boot. When you press the button, the logo of the vaio is shown and then it boot again, and again etc..

The problem is the memory that I purchased or I took a wrong one?

Comment: Does it boot with either of the 4GB sticks?

Comment: I tried it and no it doesn't boot either.

Comment: What makes you think this laptop supports booting with 8 GB?

Comment: I check it in the site i have posted. Also I checked it in eu.crucial where you can scan your system http://eu.crucial.com/eur/en/systemscanner

Comment: Test the new sticks in another machine, from what I can see here, those should work fine. If they don't work there either, RMA them for replacements.  PS: RAM will almost always downclock -- so 1333MHz RAM will downclock to 1066Mhz when used in a 1066MHZ machine.  So using 1333 in a 1066 machine is perfectly fine, and because of this, you'd probably have a hard time finding "1066" RAM these days. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sony Vaio VPCEB3M1E supports max 8 GB ( 2 x  4 GB) 1066 MHz, 1333 MHz recommended speed. 1600 MHz might also work.

You can refer manufacturer specs here:

https://www.sony.it/support/it/content/cnt-specs/VPCEB3M1E/list

To troubleshoot, remove both modules, install the new one in slot first, boot it up, if it doesn't work, try the second slot, keeping the first slot empty. Try with each of the new ones separately in both the two slots.

Either one of the module should work individually. If it doesn't work chances are, defective.

You can refer this link also:
http://www.memorystock.com/memory/SonyVAIOVPCEB3M1EBQ.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the old one had 8 modules

[image: old ram]

where the new had 4 modules.

[image]

I purchased a RAM with 8 modules and worked!

Answer (score -1):

The RAM specs you entered do not match the ones on the Sony Website. Your laptop requires PC3-8500 1066MHz. Can you confirm the 2 Gb ram you removed from the device is 1333 MHz ?

Comment: As I wrote in the question, the current ram is 1333 MHZ and is this http://www.memory4less.com/m4l_itemdetail.aspx?itemid=1443586692&partno=EBJ21UE8BDS0-DJ-F

Comment: Ok If you believe the new Ram Modules are compatible with your device, you can try booting into bios and checking to see if the computer recognises the modules. f2 should work in the window you have when there is a VAIO sign on the screen.

Also another issue (tho its farfetched) is ESD (Electrostatic Discharge). In rare cases, ESD may cuse the problem. Proper grounding might help.

Comment: Another workaround you can try is, ıf you think it's related to RAMs not getting enough energy, you can try them one by one. If a single module works but 2 does not, it can be a bad slot or not enough energy. Try If you can adjust DRAM voltage, raise it +0.05.